# Is it a good practice to do the iteration through the array in Action Creator of React Native?

Tags: arrays, if-statement, react-native, each, lodash

I have a ScrollView with data and I am currently implementing searchBar on the same page. Where would be a better practice to shrink the amount of data, that is retrieved from the firebase database based on the user's input in searchBar?
1. In the Action Creator that is currently deployed to simply fetch all the data from the database?
2. In the component itself?
3. Somewhere else?

I am planning to use lodash plugin and its .each method to iterate through the retrieved data and inside the .each method, I will use an if-statement in order to determine whether the current word in the iteration process has the string, that was retrieved from the search field. If it has - I add it to the new array, else - do nothing.

Comment: you can use the .filter method which it returns a new array with the elements that pass the if statement and the first array will remain as is.

Comment: not exactly, what I was asking, but thanks, did not know about this method.